# Storing the result of a SELECT query in an integer and reusing it in an INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which is used to insert a department into the `department` table. However, there is a foreign key to the `Address` table called `Address_ID`. Whenever i want to insert a new department, I also want to check if the address exists, and if it doesn't, I want to create a new one. If it does exist, I want to find the right ID and store it in a variable for later use. This variable is already declared as a `BIGINT` at the beginning of the code.

```
-- If the address already exists, we will select its ID and store it in a variable.
    BEGIN
      SET @Address_ID =
      (
        SELECT TOP 1 [Address_ID]
        FROM [Address]
        WHERE
          [Building] = @Building_Param
          AND [Factory] = @Factory_Param
      )
    END
```

The code above is part of a larger statement. You can find the full code below.

This segment of code fails with the following error message:

> Die @Address_ID-Tabellenvariable muss deklariert werden.

Translation:

> The @Address_ID Table variable must be declared.

Here's the full code:

```
/**
 * Inserts a new entry into the department table.
 *
 * @author     Rubbel Die Katz
 */
DECLARE @The_Date DATETIME2
SET @The_Date = GETDATE()

DECLARE @Department_Name_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Department_Name_Param = ?

DECLARE @Department_Description_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Department_Description_Param = ?

DECLARE @Factory_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Factory_Param = ?

DECLARE @Building_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Building_Param = ?

DECLARE @Address_ID BIGINT
SET @Address_ID = 0

-- If the address does not exist, we will need to create it automagically.
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Address]
    WHERE
      [Building] = @Building_Param
      AND [Factory] = @Factory_Param
)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Department] (
      [Department_Name],
      [Department_Description],
      [Time_Created],
      [Time_Modified]
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[Address_ID] INTO @Address_ID
    VALUES (
      @Department_Name_Param,
      @Department_Description_Param,
      @The_Date,
      @The_Date
    )
  END
ELSE
-- If the address already exists, we will select its ID and store it in a variable.
    BEGIN
      SET @Address_ID =
      (
        SELECT TOP 1 [Address_ID]
        FROM [Address]
        WHERE
          [Building] = @Building_Param
          AND [Factory] = @Factory_Param
      )
    END

-- If the department does not exist, we will create it using the Address_ID provided by our previous operations.
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Department] WHERE [Department_Name] = @Department_Name_Param)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [Department] (
    [Department_Name],
    [Department_Description],
    [Address_ID],
    [Time_Created],
    [Time_Modified]
  )
  VALUES (
    @Department_Name_Param,
    @Department_Description_Param,
    @Address_ID,
    @The_Date,
    @The_Date
  )
END
```

The tables that I'm using it with are all empty.

How can I get a `BIGINT` from a table as a `BIGINT`, not a table variable?

Comment: For further reading on `OUTPUT` clause - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Comment: `OUTPUT INSERTED.[Address_ID] INTO @Address_ID` - The `output` clause of an insert statement target can't be a scalar variable - it must be a table (of some kind - table variable included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some minor changes in your script. Try this:

```
DECLARE @The_Date DATETIME2
SET @The_Date = GETDATE()

DECLARE @Department_Name_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Department_Name_Param = ?

DECLARE @Department_Description_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Department_Description_Param = ?

DECLARE @Factory_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Factory_Param = ?

DECLARE @Building_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Building_Param = ?

DECLARE @Address_ID BIGINT
SET @Address_ID = 0

-- If the address does not exist, we will need to create it automagically.
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Address]
    WHERE [Building] = @Building_Param
          AND [Factory] = @Factory_Param
)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Address]
    (
      [Factory],
      [Building],
      [Time_Created],
      [Time_Modified]
    )
    VALUES
      (
        @Factory_Param,
        @Building_Param_Param,
        @The_Date,
        @The_Date
      )
  END
--Else Part is Not Neccessary

SELECT @Address_ID = [Address_ID]
--Top 1 is not needed since the variable can hold only 1 value it will take only the Top 1 by Default
FROM [Address]
WHERE
  [Building] = @Building_Param
  AND [Factory] = @Factory_Param;

-- If the department does not exist, we will create it using the Address_ID provided by our previous operations.
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM [Department]
              WHERE [Department_Name] = @Department_Name_Param)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Department]
    (
      [Department_Name],
      [Department_Description],
      [Address_ID],
      [Time_Created],
      [Time_Modified]
    )
    VALUES
      (
        @Department_Name_Param,
        @Department_Description_Param,
        @Address_ID,
        @The_Date,
        @The_Date
      )
  END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing that for me! However, the point of @Avitus still stands, so I've had to make some more adjustments. I'll suggest an edit to your post with my new, working code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear, here, you haven't declared `@Address_ID`. At the start of your batch, you'll need to `DECLARE` it:

```
DECLARE @Address_ID TABLE (AddressID BIGINT);
```

You could then get that value into a variable of the datatype `BIGINT` using:

```
DECLARE @Address_ID_BI BIGINT;
SELECT @Address_ID_BI = AddressID
FROM @Address_ID;
```

This **ASSUMES** you are only inserting one value.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't even thought of that, thanks! I'll try it and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is that you're not inserting into the address table and getting that identity value.

If you change the segment of your code from :

```
INSERT INTO [Department] (
      [Department_Name],
      [Department_Description],
      [Time_Created],
      [Time_Modified]
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[Address_ID] INTO @Address_ID
    VALUES (
      @Department_Name_Param,
      @Department_Description_Param,
      @The_Date,
      @The_Date
    )
```

To be:

```
insert into [Address] ( Building, Factory ) values ( @Building_Param, @Factory_Param ) 
set @Address_ID = ( SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() )
```

Then you'll have the address id that was inserted.

Here's the complete code for easy testing:

```
/**
 * Inserts a new entry into the department table.
 *
 * @author     Rubbel Die Katz
 */
DECLARE @The_Date DATETIME2
SET @The_Date = GETDATE()

DECLARE @Department_Name_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Department_Name_Param = ?

DECLARE @Department_Description_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Department_Description_Param = ?

DECLARE @Factory_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Factory_Param = ?

DECLARE @Building_Param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Building_Param = ?

DECLARE @Address_ID BIGINT
SET @Address_ID = 0



-- If the address does not exist, we will need to create it automagically.
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Address]
    WHERE
      [Building] = @Building_Param
      AND [Factory] = @Factory_Param
)
  BEGIN
   insert into [Address] ( Building, Factory ) values ( @Building_Param, @Factory_Param ) 
    set @Address_ID = ( SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() )
  END
ELSE
-- If the address already exists, we will select its ID and store it in a variable.
    BEGIN
      SET @Address_ID =
      (
        SELECT TOP 1 [Address_ID]
        FROM [Address]
        WHERE
          [Building] = @Building_Param
          AND [Factory] = @Factory_Param
      )
    END

-- If the department does not exist, we will create it using the Address_ID provided by our previous operations.
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Department] WHERE [Department_Name] = @Department_Name_Param)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [Department] (
    [Department_Name],
    [Department_Description],
    [Address_ID],
    [Time_Created],
    [Time_Modified]
  )
  VALUES (
    @Department_Name_Param,
    @Department_Description_Param,
    @Address_ID,
    @The_Date,
    @The_Date
  )
END
```

Comment: I just facepalmed so hard.